# Select visible xpath in list

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get the error message off of a page from a site. The list contains several possible errors so i can't check by id; but I do know that the one with display:list-item is the one I want. This is my rule but doesn't seem to work, what is wrong with it? What I want returned is the error text in the element.

```
//*[@id='errors']/ul/li[contains(@style,'display:list-item')]
```

Example dom elements:

```
<div id="errors" class="some class" style="display: block;">
<div class="some other class"></div>
<div class="some other class 2">
<span class="displayError">Please correct the errors listed in red below:</span>
<ul>
    <li style="display:none;" id="invalidId">Enter a valid id</li>
    <li style="display:list-item;" id="genericError">Something bad happened</li>
    <li style="display:none;" id="somethingBlah" ............ </li>
    ....
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Give the full HTML..at least the part of HTML,by which we can understand the XPATH you wrote..

Comment: Could you post more from the 'Example dom elements'? At least 2 a 3 elements higher..

Comment: Added more dom to question

Comment: try this *//*[@id='errors']//ul/li[contains(@style,'display:list-item')]*.. Hope will work..

Comment: If works,,,let me know I will post it as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct XPath should be:

```
//*[@id='errors']//ul/li[contains(@style,'display:list-item')]
```

After `//*[@id='errors']` you need an extra `/`, because `<ul>` is not directly beneath it. Using `//` again scans all underlying elements for `<ul>`.

If you are capable to not use `//` it would be better and faster and less consuming.

Comment: This worked. I appreciate the explanation, as I was just going to ask. I have to wait 6 more minutes to check it as the right answer. Thanks for the fast response. I learned something new.